# Angular: Disable button if value exist in object array with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have list of groups and generate that group list in HTML with `ng-repeat`(list of buttons) and its working perfectly. But in case when i am trying to disable some buttons with `ng-disabled` by call function to check the value, i just amazed my loop and buttons showing correctly but `ng-disable="myfunc()"` called many times.

**My Code:**

```
<button class="button button-block button-calm btn-shape" ng-click="startSurvey(group.survey_id,group.id)"  ng-repeat="group in groupList" ng-disabled="checkGroupCompleted($index)">
    {{group.title}}
</button>
```

**Group List:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
$scope.checkGroupCompleted = function(groupID){
        console.log(groupID);

    }
```

**Console Output:**

[image]

I just need similar functionality:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/5026/)

Comment: You are use **ng-repeat** in button it self so when loop start function it self fire many time so you can put **ng-repeat** to its parent element and then after put button inside after that you add **ng-disabled** to button and check it.

Comment: hmm...ohk got it.. thanks :)

Comment: I think its because your function is not returning anything. It needs to return `true` for enabled and `false` for disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what angular is all about. Whenever your `$scope` will get modified each time `digest` cycle will run so each and every function is going to be called.

In case of `ng-show`, `ng-show`, `ng-disabled` etc same process it follows.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.checkGroupCompleted = function(groupID) {
    return (groupID === 1);
}
```

if the value is 1 it will return true or else false

Answer (score 0):

You are use **ng-repeat** in button it self so when loop start function it self fire many time so you can put **ng-repeat** to its parent element and then after put button inside after that you add **ng-disabled** to button and check it.

For ex.

```
<div> ng-repeat=groups in group>
    <button> ng-disabled="checkGroupCompleted($index)"></button>
</div>

    $scope.checkGroupCompleted = function(groupID){
         return (groupID === 1);
    }
```